# Interact with Windows Media Player

Tags: java, windows-media-player

Is there any way that I can interact with Windows Media Player in Java. I did make a research and know how to make wmp shuffle on, repeat on, start, pause, etc. But I cannot find a way to check if the wmp is already playing or pause, or the shuffle function and the repeat function is already on, and the amount of the volume.

Anyone know a proper way in Java?

Comment: *"Is there any way that I can interact with Windows Media Player in Java."*  Not on OS X, *nix, or this Windows 7 box where WMP is not the default.  Why code this in Java?  I'd bet .Net can do it easily.

Comment: Because I just want to know if there is any way I can do that in Java.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone know a proper way in Java?

J2SE will not help, so 'no'. You will need to use natives.