# How to interact with Windows Media Player in java

Tags: java, windows-media-player

Can you help me interact with, or get information about the current song being played by Windows Media Player in java?

Comment: are you talking about the standalone program or an embedded instance of WMP inside a wrapper application? in the second case, you may develop a sort of interface to communicate with java (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interact with Windows Media Player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504062/interact-with-windows-media-player)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following link be useful:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/384480/java/java/Window-Media-Player

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible using java my mate.
Java can not able to interact with Windows media player.
You have to use `natives`.